# Workflow Foundation (WF 4.5) - states hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy, workflow-foundation

I'm try using Workflow Foundation (WF 4.5), in particular I'm interested in state machines. The purpose would be make it easier to navigate a complex state machine.

I started with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/getting-started-tutorial), then I tried to create a macro-state and I found that, once entered in the inner state machine (placed in the "Entry" of the macro-state) any transition, both internal or from bookmarks, from the macro-state to to other states were not executed. the machine is stuck in the inner state-machine.

Here my attempt of hierarchical states:

[image]

Does anyone know if WF support the hierarchically nested states (as from UML standard) and how to allow transition directly from macro-states? (without using FinalState as workaround)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Workflow does support nested states.
and as for the reason of workflow stuck in inner state-machine your inner state-machine is like an infinite loop so it won't come out.